# Protractor - Upload file Error "Element <input type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard" in firefox 58 but works fine in firefox 57

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, firefox, protractor

geckodriver - 1.10.0,
Firefox v58,
node - 8.9

1) Using below code to upload file in chrome and firefox browsers using Protractor.

```
return element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath).then(() => {  
    return browser.sleep(5000)
});
```

Works absolutely fine in all versions of Chrome and until firefox 57. When I updated the browser to latest version firefox 58, the code breaks with error 
'Element input type="file" is not reachable by keyboard'.

1) Also download file does not work in firefox using protractor but chrome does.Help on this is much appreciated. tried firefox profile but it is not working properly.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1173

Answer (score 0):

```
directConnect: false,

    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
     'moz:webdriverClick': false
    }
```

set these properties in your configuration file that will resolve the issue.